# Converting to Lambert Conformal Conic projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I am very much a beginner.  I have two maps that should line up with each other, but their projections are different.  I've tried to use the gdalwarp utility to match them up, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Here's some info

```
Sus_10m.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ../dems/Sus_10m.tif
Size is 2252, 2115
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["REGVEN / UTM zone 18N",
    GEOGCS["REGVEN",
        DATUM["Red_Geodesica_Venezolana",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6189"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4189"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2201"]]
Origin = (238238.500000000000000,4514375.500000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000444049733570,-10.001891252955083)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left  (  238238.500, 4514375.500) ( 78d 6' 0.03"W, 40d44'19.34"N)
Lower Left  (  238238.500, 4493221.500) ( 78d 5'28.35"W, 40d32'54.29"N)
Upper Right (  260759.500, 4514375.500) ( 77d50' 1.03"W, 40d44'44.02"N)
Lower Right (  260759.500, 4493221.500) ( 77d49'32.07"W, 40d33'18.80"N)
Center      (  249499.000, 4503798.500) ( 77d57'45.37"W, 40d38'49.39"N)

Band 1 Block=2252x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan

GRASS 6.4.4 (demolocation)> gdalinfo tmax_1980_11752.nc | head -n 50
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: tmax_1980_11752.nc
Size is 212, 248
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",25],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",60],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",42.5],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-100],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (1718000.000000000000000,218000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1000.000000000000000,-1000.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  lambert_conformal_conic#false_easting=0
  lambert_conformal_conic#false_northing=0
  lambert_conformal_conic#grid_mapping_name=lambert_conformal_conic
  lambert_conformal_conic#latitude_of_projection_origin=42.5
  lambert_conformal_conic#longitude_of_central_meridian=-100
  lambert_conformal_conic#standard_parallel={25,60}
  NC_GLOBAL#citation=Please see http://daymet.ornl.gov/ for current Daymet data
citation information
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.4
  NC_GLOBAL#references=Please see http://daymet.ornl.gov/ for current informatio
n on Daymet references
  NC_GLOBAL#source=Daymet Software Version 2.0
  NC_GLOBAL#start_year=1980
  NC_GLOBAL#tileid=11752
  NC_GLOBAL#Version_data=Daymet Data Version 2.1
  NC_GLOBAL#Version_software=Daymet Software Version 2.0
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={time}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_DEF={365,6}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_VALUES={0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5
,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,17.5,18.5,19.5,20.5,21.5,22.5,23.5,24.5,25.5,26.5,27.5,28.5
,29.5,30.5,31.5,32.5,33.5,34.5,35.5,36.5,37.5,38.5,39.5,40.5,41.5,42.5,43.5,44.5
,45.5,46.5,47.5,48.5,49.5,50.5,51.5,52.5,53.5,54.5,55.5,56.5,57.5,58.5,59.5,60.5
  time#bounds=time_bnds
  time#calendar=standard
  time#long_name=time
  time#units=days since 1980-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
  tmin#_FillValue=-9999
  tmin#cell_methods=area: mean time: minimum
  tmin#coordinates=lat lon
  tmin#grid_mapping=lambert_conformal_conic
  tmin#long_name=daily minimum temperature
  tmin#missing_value=-9999
  tmin#units=degrees C
  tmin#valid_range={-50,50}
  x#long_name=x coordinate of projection
  x#standard_name=projection_x_coordinate
  x#units=m
  y#long_name=y coordinate of projection
  y#standard_name=projection_y_coordinate
  y#units=m
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1565000.000,  175000.000) ( 79d53' 1.44"W, 42d21'42.83"N)
Lower Left  ( 1565000.000,  -70000.000) ( 80d36' 8.91"W, 40d 6'51.87"N)
Upper Right ( 1773000.000,  175000.000) ( 77d19'57.86"W, 41d51'49.62"N)
Lower Right ( 1773000.000,  -70000.000) ( 78d 8' 4.16"W, 39d38' 3.15"N)
Center      ( 1669000.000,   52500.000) ( 78d59'24.84"W, 41d 0' 3.70"N)
Band 1 Block=208x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=-9999
    cell_methods=area: mean time: minimum
    coordinates=lat lon
    grid_mapping=lambert_conformal_conic
    long_name=daily minimum temperature
    missing_value=-9999
    NETCDF_DIM_time=0.5
    NETCDF_VARNAME=tmin
    units=degrees C
    valid_range={-50,50}
Band 2 Block=208x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=-9999
    cell_methods=area: mean time: minimum
    coordinates=lat lon
    grid_mapping=lambert_conformal_conic
    long_name=daily minimum temperature
    missing_value=-9999
    NETCDF_DIM_time=1.5
    NETCDF_VARNAME=tmin
    units=degrees C
    valid_range={-50,50}
Band 3 Block=208x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=-9999

I used gdalwarp as such to try and convert:

GRASS 6.4.4 (demolocation)> gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:9001 -t_srs "+proj=
lcc +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +unit
s=m +no_defs" -tr 10 10 -r bilinear -multi -dstnodata 0 -of GTiff ../dems/Sus_10
m.tif Sus_10mLCC.tif
Creating output file that is 2269P x 2147L.
Processing input file ../dems/Sus_10m.tif.
Using internal nodata values (e.g. nan) for image ../dems/Sus_10m.tif.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

GRASS 6.4.4 (demolocation)>

the projection looks right, but the coordinates are off.  I overlay these on top of a DEM for the entire north american continent and the Susquehanna shall dem ends up somewhere in Idaho.. that's not right.

The proj4 string is correct, I verified it with my domain scientist.

Comment: If it's in the United States why are you starting with a Venezuelan coordinate system http://georepository.com/crs_4189/REGVEN.html is that how it was supplied? http://georepository.com/crs_2201/REGVEN-UTM-zone-18N.html and http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/regven-utm-zone-18n/ it's a **long** way from Idaho!

Comment: I really have no idea, but if you look at the upper left coordinates, you'll see that it's in Pennsylvania, which is correct.  The Susquehanna dem was supplied by OpenTopo http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/gridsphere/gridsphere?cid=geonlidarframeportlet&gs_action=lidarDataset&opentopoID=OTLAS.042013.26918.1 and the other set was provided by Daymet.  I need them to place nicely together, I'm an absolute newbie with this stuff, I'm trying to read and learn as much as I can, but I've been stuck here for quite some time.

Comment: That may be correct for WGS84/UTM Zone 17 North or WGS84/UTM Zone 18 North but not so much for REGVEN / UTM zone 18N which is based on the Red_Geodesica_Venezolana datum. Projected coordinates can only be compared within the zone as they are repeated for each zone.

Comment: I don't know gdalwarp specifics but why is EPSG:9001 specified after -s_srs? What happens if you omit that completely (let gdalwarp read the source coordsys from the raster)?

Comment: I suppose I thought I had to specify the EPSG number.  I didn't realize that gdalwarp could read the EPSG number itself.  That is a good idea,I'll give it a try.  I seem to be getting good results with some maps, and bad results with others.

Comment: The correct EPSG number is 32618 for UTM 18 North. EPSG:9001 is just the definition code for using meters, as included in the .prj file. EPSG:2201 (at the end of the .prj file) puts the data in the same place, although mainly designed for Venezuela.